# Pycharm cannot find reference `cloud` in "__init__.pyi" for google.cloud, but code does execute

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, pyenv, python-poetry

I am using poetry with `pyenv` to manage dependencies. My `pyproject.toml` looks as follows:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "hello-world"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "None"
authors = ["Hello <foo@bar.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
keywords = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<3.11"
google-cloud = "^0.34.0"
google-cloud-core = "^2.3.2" 
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer = "^3.7.1"
google-cloud-bigquery = "^3.3.2"
google-cloud-firestore = "^2.5.2"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "ngt-pypi"
url = "link/to/private/package/abc-python/simple/"
default = false
secondary = true

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Assuming pyenv is installed (and using version 3.9.6), I install the dependencies by running:

```
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
poetry install
```

After this, I confirm that in my interpreter I have the latest versions of the google cloud repositories installed.

Nevertheless, when I try to create a code and import bigquery:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

I see on the Pycharm editor that it has not been found. The code however does execute, and there are no errors.
What can be done to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your virtual env was created correctly ? for example with the command 
`which python3`

Comment: The venv is correct. It seems to be more of an issue of Pycharm as the code can execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `PyCharm` and `IntelliJ`, you can do the following actions :

- Open the menu `file/Project Structure`
- Click on SDKs and the `plus` button

[image]

- Click on the `Add Python sdk`

[image]

- Click on the `Poetry environment`

[image]

- It will detect your current `Poetry env` and create the `sdk` in `PyCharm`
- Then in `Project settings` section, select the `sdk` created previously

[image]

I usually use `Pipenv` instead of `Peoetry` but the principle is the same with `PyCharm`.

Comment: @JohnAndrews have you tried my solution on `PyCharm`?